# NullPointerException from UsbManager

Tags: android, android-emulator, usb

I have some code which looks like

```
UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
usbManager.getDeviceList();
```

When I use an Android 5.0 emulator, I get this crash:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager.getDeviceList(android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
    at android.hardware.usb.UsbManager.getDeviceList(UsbManager.java:243)
    ...
```

I understand that the official Android emulator has no USB support, but I would expect to see an empty list of USB devices rather than a crash.

I peaked in the Android code a bit, and `ServiceManager`'s map of services didn't have an entry for `"usb"`. Nothing in the Android 21 stack seems to handle the null value returned by `ServiceManager`.

The code works fine on emulated 4.4 devices, but crashes on 5.0 devices. CPU architecture doesn't seem to make a difference; I tried ARM and x86.

It also works fine on all Genymotion devices I've tried, but I need to get this working on CentOS CI hosts, and getting Genymotion to run on CentOS seems to require intrusive changes.

Any ideas for a fix or workaround? As a last resort I could catch `UsbManager`'s NPE, but it would be pretty bad as I also use a third party library which interacts with `UsbManager`.

Comment: This : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=578875 suggests that - getDevicesList doesn't work on emulators due to the emulators lack of usb support.

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String)

RETURN `Object  The service or null if the name does not exist.`

As per API, implementation is not obliged to returned a non `null` value.

Work around: simple.

```
UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
if (usbManager == null) {
    Log.w("MyApp","USB Not supported");
    return;
}

// Normal route
usbManager.getDeviceList();
```

(I have also faced the same issue on Emulator as you described)

Comment: The OP is asking about a exception in getDeviceList - not a null returned by getSystemService.

Comment: I can help you ping me zafarhussain910@gmail.com